# URL Connection (FTP) in Java - Simple Question

Tags: java, url, ftp

I have a simple question. I'm trying to upload a file to my ftp server in Java.

I have a file on my computer, and I want to make a copy of that file and upload it. I tried manually writing each byte of the file to the output stream, but that doesn't work for complicated files, like zip files or pdf files.

```
File file = some file on my computer;
String name = file.getName();
URL url = new URL("ftp://user:password@domain.com/" + name +";type=i");
URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();
OutputStream os = urlc.getOutputStream();

//then what do I do?
```

Just for kicks, here is what I tried to do:

```
OutputStream os = urlc.getOutputStream();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String line = br.readLine();
while(line != null && (!line.equals(""))) {
    os.write(line.getBytes());
    os.write("\n".getBytes());
    line = br.readLine();
}
os.close();
```

For example, when I do this with a pdf and then try and open the pdf that I run with this program, it says an error occurred when trying to open the pdf. I'm guessing because I am writing a "\n" to the file? How do I copy the file without doing this?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work?

Comment: well, I try to open the pdf that I tried to copy in this manner and it says an error ocurred with the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use any of the `Reader` or `Writer` classes when you're trying to copy the byte-for-byte exact contents of a binary file. Use these only for plain text! Instead, use the `InputStream` and `OutputStream` classes; they do not interpret the data at all, while the `Reader` and `Writer` classes interpret the data as characters. For example

```
OutputStream os = urlc.getOutputStream();
FileInputStreamReader fis = new FileInputStream(file);
byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];
int count = 0;
while((count = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    os.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

Whether your `URLConnection` usage is correct here, I don't know; using Apache Commons FTP (as suggested elsewhere) would be an excellent idea. Regardless, this would be the way to read the file.

Comment: Well, you need *both* things -- you have to read and write the file with `Input/OutputStream`s, and you need to use something like `FTPClient` to properly transmit it.

Comment: FTP clients can transfer data as text or binary.  PDFs *require* binary.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `BufferedInputStream` to read and `BufferedOutputStream` to write. Take a look at this post: http://www.ajaxapp.com/2009/02/21/a-simple-java-ftp-connection-file-download-and-upload/

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(localfilename);
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
OutputStream os =m_client.getOutputStream();
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(os);
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int readCount;
while( (readCount = bis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    bos.write(buffer, 0, readCount);
}
bos.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

FTP usually opens another connection for data transfer.
So I am not convinced that this approach with URLConnection is going 
to work.
I highly recommend that you use specialized ftp client. Apache commons 
may have one.

Check this out
http://commons.apache.org/net/api/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html

Comment: I am using FTPClient now. And the pdf still gets all messed up.

Comment: Actually (at least with Sun JRE) URLConnection handles ftp:// with sun.net.ftp.FTPClient that, even though it is undocummented, I still prefer it over commons.net.ftp.FTPClient (mainly due to proxy implementation). Just as a side note completely unrelated to the actual issue in the question :)