# Tomcat: use FTP connection via JNDI

Tags: java, tomcat, ftp, jndi

I need to access an FTP server from my Web Application which runs on Tomcat 6. I want to use JNDI to do this.

How can I configure this FTP connection in Tomcat using JNDI? 
What do I have to write into `web.xml` and `context.xml` to configure the resource? And how can I then access this connection from the Java source code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From this post : http://codelevain.wordpress.com/2010/12/18/url-as-jndi-resource/

Define your FTP URL in your context.xml like this :

```
 <Resource name="url/SomeService" auth="Container"
 type="java.net.URL"
 factory="com.mycompany.common.URLFactory"
 url="ftp://ftpserver/folder" />
```

Provide the com.mycompany.common.URLFactory implementation and make sure the resulting class is available to Tomcat :

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import javax.naming.*;
import javax.naming.spi.ObjectFactory;

public class URLFactory implements ObjectFactory {
 public Object getObjectInstance(Object obj, Name name, Context nameCtx, Hashtable environment) throws Exception {
 Reference ref = (Reference) obj;
 String urlString =  (String) ref.get("url").getContent();
 return new URL(urlString);
 }
}
```

Create your reference in web.xml

```
<resource-ref>
 <res-ref-name>
   url/SomeService
 </res-ref-name>
 <res-type>
   java.net.URL
 </res-type>
 <res-auth>
   Container
 </res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

Then in your code obtain the FTP URL by doing a JNDI lookup:

```
InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
URL url = (URL) context.lookup("java:comp/env/url/SomeService");
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need JNDI for that. Just use an `URLConnection` Java class with an URL starting with `"ftp:"`, see e. g. [URL Connection (FTP) in Java - Simple Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5925438/url-connection-ftp-in-java-simple-question)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I clarified my question: I specifically want to use JNDI to configure the FTP server.

Comment: So even the FTPClient class of the Apache commons net project does not cover your needs? See: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html