# Tomcat 9 jndi: protocol MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: jndi

Tags: java, url, jndi, tomcat9

So I have a library that is using Apache Common VFS to load resources out of the WEB-INF directory.  That resource has to be loaded with java.net.URL because that is what VFS uses underneath.  Here is the URL:

```
jndi:/localhost/WEB-INF/config/some.xml
```

This worked great in Tomcat 7, but it's not working in Tomcat 9 which is mentioned in the documentation.  But I can't find any details on how to change the URL so it's happy again.  I can't find any examples of jdni: urls other than EJB and DataSource.

Here is the underlying exception:

```
MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: jndi
```

I can't even find what class was providing the jndi protocol.

Any ideas?

Comment: In case it helps: Tomcat does not have an out-of-the-box factory for `java:comp/env/url` (unlike JDBC) so you have to write your own URL factory. The answer (and link) in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18351869/tomcat-use-ftp-connection-via-jndi) shows how. (I don't know if the URL will provide access to a file in `WEB-INF`, though.) Some more Tomcat-specific background is [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html#Adding_Custom_Resource_Factories).

Comment: Hi @andrewjames But the jdni: protocol was supported in Tomcat 7, and it stopped working in Tomcat 8/9.  I checked back 5 years in my git repo I've been using jndi URL for over 5 years because I couldn't remember why I was using it exactly.  Now I just think it's because I need to refer to things in WEB-INF through URL and this is the only way to do it.  So what changed?

Comment: Sorry - I know that is the point of your question, but I have no idea what may have changed. The closest I see is [this](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=1831256) in 8.0 - but the error message does not match yours (and it was rolled back in 8.5, anyway). My comment was tangential at best.

Comment: Yea I've looked through parts of the code, and I can't find any URL factory in the code base.  I did find TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory which defines a war: URL, but all examples are like war:file:/full/path/what/good/is/this.